# Get gradle build path folder from java

Tags: java, gradle, java-8

I running a logger test that create some logs, and since I want those to be automatically deleted after the test pass or in the next gradle build execution, I would like to output the files into the build gradle folder.

I´ve been looking how to point as relative path the build gradle folder from Java, but I could not find any answer.

My test is in the folder structure

```
 Project->src->main->java
```

And I would like to output the files into

```
 Project->build
```

Any idea how to get that relative path?

**SOLUTION**

```
   String projectPath = System.getProperty("user.dir");
   rollingFileAppender.setFile(projectPath + File.separator + "/build/policy_rule_test.log");
```

Comment: do you want to know where the project is stored

Comment: Just to get the relative path, but I found solution already

Answer (score 2):

Obviously `user.dir + '/build'` works as you have figured out, but gradle does have a variable for build directory, which is `buildDir`.

Of these two ways, I would recommend using `buildDir` just so if a plugin or someone decides to change output directory by setting `buildDir`, you're still covered for the cleanup.

Comment: go do you get buildDir from Java?, can you provide code exmaple please?

Comment: I apologize, I misunderstood your question. Thought you wanted build directory in your gradle script as opposed to your java code. You can either write a system prop or to a properties file from build.gradle and then consume that from your java code. Both of these are more laborious than your solution.